# Definite article confusion

Tags: definite-article

I have read rules on using articles... They say we should not put an article before names of lakes like **Lake Erie**, **Lake Kissimmee**, **Lake Rabun**.
But we do use **the** with groups of lakes like **the Great Lakes**
But I have read two examples that I can not understand, why is **THE** used:

- Go jump in the lake.
- The lake was frozen.
- We swam in the lake.

Answer (score 1):

**[Do not use the before the names of lakes (Lake Erie, Lake Kissimmee, Lake Rabun)](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/geographical-use-the/)** The word **"lake"** is just a simple noun so you need to plate an article before it, it's not a name.

- Let's go to Lake Michigan. *(no article)*
- I don't won't to go to **the** lake, I want to go to **the** river.
- Okay, let's go to **the** Illinois River.

Comment: Since you used a river in your example phrases, it might be nice to add an explanation in your answer as to why a definite article is used with some geographic bodies and not others.  I know your link does explain that, but the answer is a little bit confusing as-is, because the examples don't directly relate to the answer.